# how to grab a specific line after the line I found by parsing in python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am currently parsing an xml file to find the a pattern and extract what i need from inside it.

is there a way so that when i find the line i am looking for to count two lines down and grab that line.

```
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        if pattern.search(line):
            #parse each line returned and return only the host names
            result = re.findall('"([^"]*)"',line )
            print(result)
```

example xml

```
<Computer3Properties name="UH25">
        <Description property="Description">
          <DescriptionValue value="lab" type="VTR" />
```

output

```
UH25
```

Desired output

```
UH25
lab
```

now i cant reparse the file and look for the pattern because there are many instances of

```
   <DescriptionValue value=
```

so i have to grab it once i find the hostname go down the rows and scrape the data inside value

Comment: Can't you just add two lines of f.readline() and keep the second one as a variable?

Comment: not sure how to grab that specific line once i find the pattern -@arara

Comment: `next(f)` will return the next line in the file from your current position.  So call `line = next(f)` twice, and `line` will be the line you want.

Comment: i used for for loop with range of 2 and it seems to do the trick the only problem is now i am getting both values in the line that are inside "" .. `['lab', 'VTR']`, how would i write a regex that deletes this out of a line type = "" that would  also delete everything inside the ""

Answer (score 1):

I created an example.xml file containing the exact example contents you specified:

```
<Computer3Properties name="UH25">
        <Description property="Description">
          <DescriptionValue value="lab" type="VTR" />
```

This code:

```
import re

pattern = "UH25"

with open("path","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.search(pattern,line):
            file.readline()
            print(file.readline())
```

will print whichever line comes two lines after the line where the pattern match was found. Using the example file, you get ''. The reason why this prints two lines down is that the readline() method will grab the contents of the *next* line. Using it two times (as I did) will print the second line from the line with the match. You said your desired output was specifically printing 'lab' from this line. If so, only the print() line needs to be slightly modified:

```
import re

pattern = "UH25"

hostnames = []

with open("path","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.search(pattern,line):
            hostnames += re.findall(pattern,line)
            file.readline()
            hostnames.append(file.readline().split('"')[1])
    
for x in hostnames:
    print(x)
```

Comment: My pattern finds multiple hostnames it wont be always UH25 this kept on printing my pattern regex and what i needed. what i want is to whenever i find a match set it to a list called hostnames and go down and set the data inside value to be in another list for location

Comment: so in your example xml you have to duplicate them multiple times and change the hostname and the value for description.

Comment: Well of course you're going to be finding different patterns then UH25, that's just the example. The point of my answer is to explain how you can grab information from the second line after the one where you get a match (i.e. by grabbing the second instance of file.readline()). I modified my answer to deal with appending to a list called hostnames as you suggest here, but it now feels like what you're asking to do is a separate question?